# How to call a function a fixed number of times after fixed intervals in javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to call an on event function a fixed number of times and after fixed interval of time.

Example of the code which is not working

```
function work(i){
   remove();
   draw(i);          
 } 

d3.select("body").select('button').on('click', function() {
 for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
   setTimeout(function(i){
     remove();
     draw(i);
    },1500);                                    
   }
 });
```

What is the problem with my code and please provide the solution.

Comment: How is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your `setTimeout` calls are made immediately after each other in the loop and do not wait for each other to complete. You can use `setInterval` to achieve the functionality you requrie:

```
function work(i) {
   remove();
   draw(i);          
} 

d3.select("body").select('button').on('click', function () {
    work(0);
    var times = 1,
        myInterval = setInterval(function () {
            work(times);
            times++;
            if (times === 7) {
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
        }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: Or you could set the timeout to `1500*(i+1)`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff is it more or less expensive to run multiple concurrent `setTimeouts` or a single `setInterval`?

Comment: until the function in setTimeout runs after 1.5 seconds ,how can for loop start next iteration?

Comment: @user3074097 by that do you mean you need `remove(); draw(times);` functions to be called immediately and not made to wait for 1.5 seconds? If so I will update my answer?

Comment: @Jonathan I wouldn't expect it to be more expensive to run multiple concurrently. That said, I haven't measured it and for 7 it certainly won't make a measurable difference in practice.

Comment: @Jonathan Your solution is working.but I didn't get to know problem with my approach.

Comment: @user3074097 the problem was that the for loop does not wait for the setTimeout to execute so it is starting the first setTimeout then the next, then the next and so on, with very little gap between them. This means that they effectively all execute at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple soln using `setTimeout`

```
function work(i){
   remove();
   draw(i); 
   if(i<=7){//set your condition
    setTimeout(function(i){
      i++;
      work(i);
    },1500); 
   }         
 } 

d3.select("body").select('button').on('click', function() {
  work(0);
});
```

I think, using `setTimeout` is safer than `setInterval`